# Any PowerPC simulator suggestions?

Tags: simulator, qemu, powerpc

I'm about to start learning PowerPC architecture and as an example of I've downloaded some reference manuals from NXP website as well as theirs SDK so I can build even bareboard applications. To be precise I'm using virtual host environment. I don't have any board with PowerPC processor on it so I would like to use a simulator for debugging.
At this step I'm a little confused. So, I've built an bareboard application (a 'Hello World' one). And now I'd like to run it with simulator. I've tried to use a command like this: `qemu-system-ppc -machine ppce500 -cpu e500v2 -nographic -kernel ./a.out` and saw nothing. The `qemu` just loads host CPU. `./a.out` is the binary built with command `$CC -static ./tst.c`. So, now I don't even know how to deal with `qemu`.
For those, who would like to help: I'm using Virtual Host environment for Freescale P1010 processor with e500v2 core, the binary was built with theirs `fsl-*` utilities.

The source compiled was:

```
$ cat ./tst.c
#include <unistd.h>
#define STRING "This is a test.\n"
int main(void) {
    write(1, STRING, sizeof(STRING) - 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation took place like:

```
$ echo $CC
powerpc-fsl-linux-gnuspe-gcc -m32 -mcpu=8548 -mabi=spe -mspe -mfloat-gprs=double --sysroot=/opt/fsl-qoriq/1.9/sysroots/ppce500v2-fsl-linux-gnuspe
$ $CC -static -o tst.bin ./tst.c
$ file ./tst.bin
./tst.bin: ELF 32-bit MSB executable, PowerPC or cisco 4500, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=63b307e7afe9de0b2781f2f92b5f1b3a803f850d, not stripped
```

Answer (score 2):

Other than using a simulator, Why don't you ask for a real free virtual machine to do development/learning? From what you say, it should work better.

You can ask a VM in the following sites:

[**Brazil**] http://openpower.ic.unicamp.br/minicloud/

[**China**] https://dashboard.ptopenlab.com

Comment: A virtual machine would be nice too. I've used word `simulator` to generalize the need. Thanks for the links. Anyway, that minicloud site offers to use some OS. What I need is virtualization or simulation of bare processor to have an ability to explore the architecture with practice, not just the theory.

Answer (score 2):

You're not seeing anything as you're asking qemu-system-powerpc to run a userspace binary rather than a kernel.

If you're just wanting to poke at userspace programming, try the qemu-ppc binary instead, as that will run 32bit PowerPC userspace by doing things like translating syscalls.

Another option, if you want to program the bare metal, is to start writing your own tiny OS to a specific machine type (i.e. you're going to have to implement that write() call you're calling).